# Beam profile of alpha particles

Tags: experimental-physics

Reading about the Rutherford gold foil experiment, I came across [this](http://web.mit.edu/wangfire/pub8.13/rutherpaper.pdf) paper (Emily P. Wang, 2004). In section 4, the alpha particles' beam profile (count rate as function of angle) is found to be "approximately triangular", as shown in Figure 3 in the paper:
[image]

This behavior is explained in the paper as follows:

> The explanation for this shape can be understood by recognizing the fact that the beam profile represents the convolution between the shape of the alpha particle beam emerging from the source and the shape of the detector. The alpha particle beam is highly collimated and can hence be considered to have an angular behavior that is roughly square. The detector is sensitive and detects any particle that impinges upon it, so its behavior can also be considered to be a square. The convolution of two square profiles will be triangular, and this is what we observe in the beam profile.

Why does the convolution of the "actual" beam's profile with the detector's profile give the observed beam profile? What does the convolution physically mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of us who spent many hours slaving over an ion accelerator to crank out Rutherford Backscattering Spectrometry spectra to measure composition profiles in thin films, the accuracy of backscattering theory seems to have been pretty well established over the last 50+ years. But, that paper seems like a nice physics laboratory write up.

But, your question was on the convolution, which is not particularly well explained (a diagram would have been quite usefule!). However, the best I can come up with is:

Assume a square profile beam (the alphas) propagating in one direction. Now take your square detector, with the square roughly the same size as the beam. Translate the detector perpendicular to the beam, starting with the detector out of the beam. At first, the detector sees nothing. When it first encounters the beam, you start getting counts. Then, for each $\delta x$ you translate the detector you get an increase in counts proportional to $\delta x$. Eventually the detector has alphas hitting the entire area and you have maximum counts. If the detector and beam are the same size, any further translation of the detector now starts to decrease the counts, again proportionally to $\delta x$.

Should the beam be much larger than the detector, one would see a linear increase, a flat top, then a linear decrease. So, they need to be similar in size.

Comment: Interesting. I think I get the intuition, but if I indeed get a flat top, what would be the mathematical function (counts/sec as function of angle) I would fit my data to, considering the convolution presented in the lab write-up in the original post actually looks like a triangle and does not have a flat top? I the assumption that the beam is "rectangular" wrong and in fact it should be some kind of Gaussian (whose convolution with the rectangular detector might give a more appropriate shape)?

Comment: @occd2000 - indeed, there are a myriad of possible combinations of beam profile and aperture/detector shape that might have to be considered. One would expect some rise/fall shape running from linear to sine-like, and then the only question is whether there is a flat-top or not.